# Define position Logo on Top Bar iPhone App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating an iPhone App and I added a logo to the top bar, but it moves. I want it to have always the same postion. Here's what happening.

```
 self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top.png"]]; //set you logo png in navbar
```

The logo changes when the app opens: [image]

When the user is loged in (button shows logout): http://freeworldapps.com/2.PNG

Comment: Look at setting the `width` of the `UIBarButtonItem`s you're using so that they don't change

Comment: Or perhaps the `possibleTitles` property of those items.

Answer (score 0):

Your title image is being squished by the logout button. You should make it as thin as possible to avoid running into the left and right bar button items.